# get xml node value

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

The xml below  has a attribute Itemcount(`<rs:data ItemCount="4">`) . how do i get the value of that  via code.
xmldocument.childnodes.count does not give me a correct count

I need to get the count of the child nodes i.e Itemcount

```
    <listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">

<rs:data ItemCount="4">

   <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_UniqueId="1;#{DF5B35E4-D3EB-4E16-9D6F-23F368CDE05C}"/>


 <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_UniqueId="2;#{83803774-A2F6-4265-AD73-E8600ECFCE04}"/>


<z:row ows_Attachments="0"  ows_UniqueId="3;#{8B1C0737-EAA2-4313-BEC3-A5A907341856}"/>

 <z:row ows_Attachments="0"  ows_UniqueId="5;#{65CA20E9-E427-412C-A98B-367DDEBE8911}"/>

</rs:data>
</listitems>
```

Comment: `childnodes.count` would give you the number of child nodes, thats why it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//xmlStr contains your xml as a string
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);

XNamespace rs = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset";

string[] result = xml.Descendants(rs + "data")
                     .Select(node => node.Attribute("ItemCount").Value)
                     .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

prints:

```
4
```